# How i can get 100% real IP and MAC address of PC using C#

Tags: c#, ip

I am getting IP and MAC of the PC for socket connection but the problem is in PC there are 2 3 adapters for network interface like I have Wi-fi and LAN also so sometime it's giving wrong IP Address and my socket connection goes wrong.

Following is my code to get IP Address

```
public static string GetIPAddress()
{
    string Response = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        var ni = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        foreach (NetworkInterface item in ni)
        {
            if (item.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up) //&& item.NetworkInterfaceType == ?
            {
                foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in item.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                {
                    if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork & !IPAddress.IsLoopback(ip.Address))
                    {
                        Response = ip.Address.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
    return Response;
}
```

Comment: You mean there's a way to get it 80% real? More seriously, what do you mean by "*100% real*"?

Comment: You're only going to get the last IP in the list.... not all...

Answer (score 1):

You are probably reading the `IPv6` address.
Or, if the Ethernet interface `OperationalStatus` is Up but not connected - possibly because of a missing DHCP reference, the Automatic Private IP Address with a Link Layer [Suffix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.unicastipaddressinformation.suffixorigin(v=vs.110).aspx) (e.g. `169.254.0.0` → `169.254.80.104`).

One possible way to determine whether the IP Address is a *working* IP, is testing the [`IsDnsEligible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipaddressinformation.isdnseligible(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the [UnicastIPAddressInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.unicastipaddressinformation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class, which can be accessed using the [NetworkInterface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface(v=vs.110).aspx) [`GetIPProperties()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getipproperties(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

This will exclude all non-routable addresses (Private, Loopback etc.).
Also, if you know that your connection will have to use a specific transport (Ethernet, WiFi, Tunnel, Atm etc.), you can also test the `NetworkInterface` [NetworkInterfaceType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.networkinterfacetype(v=vs.110).aspx) property. See the enumeration values: [NetworkInterfaceType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterfacetype(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

NetworkInterface[] Interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

//Get all the IPv4 addresses
List<NetworkInterface> IPV4Interfaces = Interfaces
    .Where(IF => (IF.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv4)))
    .ToList();

//Utility list which collects informations on all the IPv4 interfaces
List<NetWorkInterfacesInfo> NetInterfacesInfo = IPV4Interfaces.Select(IF => new NetWorkInterfacesInfo()
{
    Name = IF.Name,
    Description = IF.Description,
    Status = IF.OperationalStatus,
    Speed = IF.Speed,
    InterfaceType = IF.NetworkInterfaceType,
    MAC = IF.GetPhysicalAddress(),
    DnsServers = IF.GetIPProperties().DnsAddresses.Select(ipa => ipa).ToList(),
    IPAddresses = IF.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses.Select(ipa => ipa.Address).ToList(),
    Gateways = IF.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.Select(ipa => ipa.Address).ToList(),
    DHCPEnabled = IF.GetIPProperties().GetIPv4Properties().IsDhcpEnabled,
    BytesSent = IF.GetIPStatistics().BytesSent,
    BytesReceived = IF.GetIPStatistics().BytesReceived
}).ToList();


//Utility container class for the NetInterfacesInfo list
public class NetWorkInterfacesInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public PhysicalAddress MAC { get; set; }
    public List<IPAddress> IPAddresses { get; set; }
    public List<IPAddress> DnsServers { get; set; }
    public List<IPAddress> Gateways { get; set; }
    public bool DHCPEnabled { get; set; }
    public OperationalStatus Status { get; set; }
    public NetworkInterfaceType InterfaceType { get; set; }
    public Int64 Speed { get; set; }
    public Int64 BytesSent { get; set; }
    public Int64 BytesReceived { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can identify a valid/routable IP Address filtering the list:

```
//Extract the Dns Eligible IP addresses
if (IPV4Interfaces != null)
{
    List<UnicastIPAddressInformation> RoutableIpAddresses =
        IPV4Interfaces.Select(IF => IF.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses.Last())
                      .Where(UniIP => UniIP.IsDnsEligible).ToList();
}
```

Or use more filters to select, for example, all routable IP Addresses with a Wireless transport:

```
if (IPV4Interfaces != null)
{
    List<UnicastIPAddressInformation> RoutableIpAddresses =
        IPV4Interfaces.Where(IF => IF.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211)
                      .Select(IF => IF.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses.Last())
                      .Where(UniIP => UniIP.IsDnsEligible).ToList();
}
```