# How to get wireless lan ip address in vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I want to get the local wlan ip of my computer. my computer is connected to both lan and wifi. I am getting the lan ip by using following program but not getting wlan ip. How to get it??

```
Private Function GetIPv4Address() As String


            GetIPv4Address = String.Empty
            Dim strHostName As String = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
            Dim iphe As System.Net.IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName)

            For Each ipheal As System.Net.IPAddress In iphe.AddressList
                If ipheal.AddressFamily = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
                    GetIPv4Address = ipheal.ToString()
                End If
            Next
```

This program get the ip address of last connected ip of lan and wlan but i want only wlan ip at any condition

and the following program shows the lan ip only

Dim mem As String

```
Private Sub GetIPAddress1()

    Dim strHostName As String
    Dim strIPAddress As String
    strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
    strIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()

    mem = strIPAddress
    MessageBox.Show("IP Address: " & strIPAddress)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NetworkInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Net.NetworkInformation);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) class to access all informations on your Network Interfaces.

When enumerating the [NetworkInterface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) collection, using the [NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) method, you can add a filter to select only the Interfaces that have a [`NetworkInterfaceType = NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterfacetype?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2).

When/if the requested Interface is found, we just need to extract the IPv4 [UnicastAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.unicastaddresses?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPInterfaceProperties.UnicastAddresses);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2), which contains, among other details, the [IPAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Net.IPAddress);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation

Dim WirelessIPAddress As IPAddress = GetWirelessIPAddress()
'If the string form is required:
Dim WLSIPAddress As String = WirelessIPAddress.ToString()

Public Function GetWirelessIPAddress() As IPAddress
    Return NetworkInterface.
        GetAllNetworkInterfaces().
        FirstOrDefault(Function(NI) NI.NetworkInterfaceType = NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211).
        GetIPProperties().
        UnicastAddresses.Last().
        Address
End Function
```

See [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50695893/how-i-can-get-100-real-ip-and-mac-address-of-pc-using-c-sharp?answertab=active#tab-top) (`C#`) to extract more informations on the interfaces.